# build the project is error and unable build it or run it in Xcode

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

this error appears when build the project and connot make Build

[image: the image is here]

Comment: You should edit the question and put the message instead of an image

Answer (score 1):

Error is showing that you need to enable bitcode or update Library if you read it.

To enable bitcode do this :

```
Go in build settings of Pod > Search Bitcode > Make it YES.
```

[image]

Comment: not solve the problems

Comment: @BasimHammad Go in Pods and then select FBLoginKit pod and go in build setting of that pod and enable it if it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

**Case:- 1**

Try cleaning the Code by `cmd + shift + K`

Then try to Build it again `cmd + B`

And then try and this might solve your issue

**Case:-2**

Or else if it does not work:

**try revealing the log by right clicking on the error and it will guide you.**

[image]

**Case:-3**  If the issue might be in the pod installation.

Make sure you are using `.xcworkspace` and not the `.xcodeproj` after the pod installation. Also try re-installing the pod by `pod install`

**Case:-4**  Try removing any of the newly installed podfile.

**Case:- 5**  If using the bridging-header File, then remove any new `#import` File

**Case:- 6** Cross check if you have used `import Foundation`

**Case 7:-** Try deleting `Derived Data` and then `clean` the build

**In last case, Remove all the pods you have used and then re install them.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: not solve the problem

Comment: @BasimHammad Edited the Answer with different cases

Comment: the same problem

Comment: @BasimHammad Have you tried all the 7 case i have stated in Answer.

Comment: yes i tried all cases

Answer (score 1):

The image shows about ENABLE_BITCODE keyword in your build settings

[image: ENABLE_BITCODE default value]

It says like you need to enable it, might be the frameworks you are using needs it. Can you try this one. hope this helps you.